# Is there a difference between read_table and read_csv in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've tested it and also checked the documentation with no visible differences.Either way i wanted to ask just in case.

Do you think that read_csv should be used only for csv's even though it works for other types? while read_table works for anything? and if they're the same while they exist?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get either to work for general delimited files, the difference are the default params, for instance `sep` is `'\t'` (tab) for `read_table` but `','` for `read_csv`. They're both implemented the same underneath

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L657)

they call the same function with different separators:

```
read_csv = _make_parser_function('read_csv', sep=',')
read_csv = Appender(_read_csv_doc)(read_csv)

read_table = _make_parser_function('read_table', sep='\t')
read_table = Appender(_read_table_doc)(read_table)
```

and [`_make_parser_function`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L495):

```
def _make_parser_function(name, sep=','):
```

is a general method which accepts the `sep` arg

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** [Upon discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25220), it was decided to **keep** the `read_table`, so this function is now [***undeprecated***](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25220#issuecomment-506848168).

<s>If you check out ~~ the [Pandas documentation for `read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html):</s>

> *[Deprecated](https://techterms.com/definition/deprecated) since version 0.24.0.*
>
> Use `pandas.read_csv()` instead, passing `sep='\t'` if necessary.

So it is advised **not** to use `read_table()`.

Comment: This note has been removed from the documentation. It no longer appears to be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The **only** difference is in fact the default value for the `sep` argument.

`read_csv` uses `sep=','`, `read_table` uses `sep='\t'` and that's it.

We can confirm this with the help of the `inspect` module by getting the signature [parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.parameters) as ordered mappings.

```
import inspect                                                                                                     
import pandas as pd                                                                                                

params_csv = inspect.signature(pd.read_csv).parameters                                                                
params_table = inspect.signature(pd.read_table).parameters
```

There are only two elements in the symmetric difference of the parameters which both correspond to the `sep` argument and its different default value for the two functions.

```
>>> params_csv.items() ^ params_table.items()                                                                                
{('sep', <Parameter "sep=','">), ('sep', <Parameter "sep='\t'">)}
```