# Parsing live stream to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parsing, dataframe

I've got some data that's coming through on a TCP port and I'm trying to parse it into a dataframe that is updated continuously. The python code I have so far to read the stream is below.

```
import socket
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024  

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print ("Connection address:", addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print ("received data:", data)
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

output - When the code runs it gathers packets that look like this. The \r\n 
starts and ends each packet, the first 4 numbers identify the column it should go in and the remaining numbers are the value. For example in the first packet 0105 indicates a date is being sent and 180511 indicates 5/11/18 for today's date. The second column is time (0106) and 14:54:02 is the time. The third column is Vendor (1984) and Erdos Miller is the value.

```
Connection address: ('127.0.0.1', 49567)
received data: b'&&\r\n0105180511\r\n0106145402\r\n1984Erdos Miller\r\n0120 
0\r\n0123 0\r\n01240\r\n01219.43\r\n011212.60\r\n01080.00\r\n01100.00\r\n
011438.89\r\n011538.89\r\n01160.00\r\n01170.00\r\n01130.00\r\n01180.00\r\n
01190.00\r\n01410.000000\r\n01420.000000\r\n01430.000000\r\n
01440.000000\r\n01450.000000\r\n!!\r\n'
```

How would I go about separating each packet as it comes through into a data frame with the appropriate columns? Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Updated output: eyllanesc recommended the bytearray and decode functions and it's getting much closer. Thanks

```
Connection address: ('127.0.0.1', 50317)
received data: &&
0105180511
0106173020
1984Erdos Miller
0120 0
0123 0
0124 0
0121-7.97
01129.45
01080.00
01100.00
011438.91
011538.91
01160.00
01170.00
01130.00
01180.00
01190.00
01410.000000
01420.000000
01430.000000
01440.000000
01450.000000
!!
```

Comment: show how you send the data

Comment: The data is coming from a WITS simulator made by Erdos Miller, it's representative of a typical WITS protocol that is only used in the oil industry, so it's difficult to find a lot of information on.

Comment: Well, it's hard to help, at least it provides what output you should get based on what you receive

Comment: try with: `print ("received data:", bytearray(data).decode())`

Comment: can you correct the indentation in your while loop

Comment: @ChadL What output do you expect? According to what I see you know how to interpret the first rows, what about the other rows?

Comment: I'll do a little more research and come back to this, your initial comment has me headed down the right track, but I think I need more basic knowledge to ask a good question at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringIO` library together with `pd.read_cvs()` function, here is how you put your stream of lines into a DF divided in columns:

```
from io import StringIO
...


while True:
    msg = mysock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    msg_string=str(msg,'utf-8')
    # print(msg_string)
    
    #stream message into a pd.df 
    read_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(msg_string) , sep=";", error_bad_lines=False, 
                            index_col=None, header=None, decimal = '.')

    print(read_df)
```

Simple explanation:

StringIO "divides" the stream into lines, while then you use `pd.read_csv` to split the lines in columns

Read documentation of `pd.read_csv` here : [pandas.read_csv() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) , setting the parameters properly for your specific case.

If you want to investigate more, you may want to try also `pd.read_table` instead, which have some differences, more info here too: [Pandas read_csv()  vs.  read_table()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681250/is-there-a-difference-between-read-table-and-read-csv-in-pandas/41681300#41681300)

After that you may want to append the DF you just created into a more general DF which collects all the readings:

```
general_DF = general_DF.append(read_DF)
```

Although is not a great practice to make DFs grow (eg. append recursively) , it may be useful as starting point for your project.

Hope this is useful to you, I haven't tried with your data, but I use this same script on a daily basis.